# Did any catholic theologian argue that hell must be eternal from the fact of Incarnation?

Tags: catholicism, hell, incarnation

Did any catholic theologian argue that hell must be eternal from the fact of Incarnation? If so, which ones, and how did they argue for it?

According to the Catholic faith, hell is eternal. Could one argue for that fact from the fact that Christ took human flesh *for our salvation?* For it seems hardly fitting that Christ would take human flesh so that we can be saved from a temporary punishment.

Comment: This is not at all clear to me. I cannot see the connection (within the terms stated in the question) between 1. The taking of human _flesh_ and the immortality of the _soul_ 2. The unspecified context of a suggested _temporary punishment_ 3. The connection of Christ's incarnation to the creation of the first humanity (Adam). I think more detail and clarity is needed in order to fully explain how the incarnation of the Son of God _proves_ the immortality of created humanity.

Comment: Related: Blessed John Duns Scotus argued that Christ would have incarnated even if man had not sinned. [This article](https://conciliarpost.com/theology-spirituality/salvation/above-all-the-glory-of-christ-john-duns-scotus-on-the-incarnation/) may lead to sources arguing both sides of that debate. I don't believe any have argued specifically that Christ would not have incarnated if the punishment for sin were not eternal death.